# How to use binary extensions

Tags: abi, abigen

[eosio.cdt v1.4.3 introduced binary extensions](https://medium.com/eosio/eosio-version-1-4-3-and-eosio-cdt-version-1-4-0-release-6542a82bcbe8#4019). Seems useful from it's description. But I wasn't able to find any docs or examples on how to use it.

There are some examples [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5600) on how to use it in abi files. But is it possible to make abi generator generate these extensions from code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent example of how to use binary extensions: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/ab8002109adc4f39d17c7ac38c4d8582af74190a/docs/guides/binary-extension.md

I will post the full text here for the case that the link gets taken down, and also it helps with SEO:

> ### eosio::binary_extension
>
> Let's fully explain what the `eosio::binary_extension` type is, what
>   it does, and why we need it for contract upgrades in certain
>   situations.
>
> You can find the implementation of `eosio::binary_extension` in the
>   `eosio.cdt` repository in file:
>   `eosio.cdt/libraries/eosiolib/core/eosio/binary_extension.hpp`.
>
> Our primary concern when using this type is when we are adding a new
>   field to a smart contract's data structure that is currently utilized
>   in an `eosio::multi_index` type (AKA a *table*), or when adding a new
>   parameter to an action declaration.
>
> By wrapping the new field in an `eosio::binary_extension`, you are
>   enabling your contract to be backwards compatible for future use. Note
>   that this new field/parameter **MUST** be appended at the end of a
>   data structure (this is due to implementation details in
>   `eosio::multi_index`, which relies on the `boost::multi_index` type),
>   or at the end of the parameter list in an action declaration.
>
> If you don't wrap the new field in an `eosio::binary_extension`, the
>   `eosio::multi_index` table will be reformatted in such a way that
>   disallows reads to the former datum; or in an action's case, the
>   function will be uncallable.
>
> ---
>
> But let's see how the `eosio::binary_extension` type works with a good
>   example.
>
> Take a moment to study this smart contract and its corresponding
>   `.abi`.
>
> This contract not only serves as a good example to the
>   `eosio::binary_extension` type, but can also be used as a gateway for
>   developing smart contracts on the eosio protocol.
>
> **binary_extension_contract.hpp**
>
> ```
> #include <eosio/contract.hpp>         // eosio::contract
> #include <eosio/binary_extension.hpp> // eosio::binary_extension
> #include <eosio/datastream.hpp>       // eosio::datastream
> #include <eosio/name.hpp>             // eosio::name
> #include <eosio/multi_index.hpp>      // eosio::indexed_by, eosio::multi_index
> #include <eosio/print.hpp>            // eosio::print_f
>
> class [[eosio::contract]] binary_extension_contract : public
> eosio::contract { public:    using contract::contract;   
> binary_extension_contract(eosio::name receiver, eosio::name code,
> eosio::datastream<const char*> ds)
>       : contract{receiver, code, ds}, _table{receiver, receiver.value}    { }
>
>    [[eosio::action]] void regpkey (eosio::name primary_key);          
> ///< Register primary key.    [[eosio::action]] void
> printbyp(eosio::name primary_key);                ///< Print by
> primary key.    [[eosio::action]] void printbys(eosio::name
> secondary_key);              ///< Print by secondary key.   
> [[eosio::action]] void modifyp (eosio::name primary_key, eosio::name
> n); ///< Modify primary key by primary key.    [[eosio::action]] void
> modifys (eosio::name primary_key, eosio::name n); ///< Modify
> secondary key by primary key.
>
>    struct [[eosio::table]] structure {
>       eosio::name _primary_key;
>       eosio::name _secondary_key;
>
>       uint64_t primary_key()   const { return _primary_key.value;   }
>       uint64_t secondary_key() const { return _secondary_key.value; }    };
>
>    using index1 = eosio::indexed_by<"index1"_n,
> eosio::const_mem_fun<structure, uint64_t, &structure::primary_key>>;  
> using index2 = eosio::indexed_by<"index2"_n,
> eosio::const_mem_fun<structure, uint64_t, &structure::secondary_key>>;
> using table  = eosio::multi_index<"table"_n, structure, index1,
> index2>;
>
> private:    table _table; };
> ```
>
> **binary_extension_contract.cpp**
>
> ````
> #include "binary_extension_contract.hpp"
>
> using eosio::name;
>
> [[eosio::action]] void binary_extension_contract::regpkey(name
> primary_key) {    eosio::print_f("`regpkey` executing.\n");
>        auto index{_table.get_index<"index1"_n>()}; ///< `index` represents `_table` organized by `index1`.    auto iter
> {index.find(primary_key.value) }; ///< Note: the type returned by
> `index.find` is different than the type returned by `_table.find`.
>        if (iter == _table.get_index<"index1"_n>().end()) {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % not found; registering.\n", primary_key.to_string());
>       _table.emplace(_self, [&](auto& row) {
>          row._primary_key   = primary_key;
>          row._secondary_key = "nothin"_n;
>       });    }    else {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % found; not registering.\n", primary_key.to_string());    }
>
>    eosio::print_f("`regpkey` finished executing.\n"); }
>
> [[eosio::action]] void binary_extension_contract::printbyp(eosio::name
> primary_key) {    eosio::print_f("`printbyp` executing.\n");
>        auto index{_table.get_index<"index1"_n>()};    auto iter {index.find(primary_key.value) };
>        if (iter != _table.get_index<"index1"_n>().end()) {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % found; printing.\n", primary_key.to_string());
>       eosio::print_f("{%, %}\n", iter->_primary_key, iter->_secondary_key);    }    else {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % not found; not printing.\n", primary_key.to_string());    }
>
>    eosio::print_f("`printbyp` finished executing.\n"); }
>
> [[eosio::action]] void binary_extension_contract::printbys(eosio::name
> secondary_key) {    eosio::print_f("`printbys` executing.\n");
>        auto index{_table.get_index<"index2"_n>()};    auto iter {index.find(secondary_key.value)};
>        if (iter != _table.get_index<"index2"_n>().end()) {
>       eosio::print_f("`_secondary_key`: % found; printing.\n", secondary_key.to_string());
>       printbyp(iter->_primary_key);    }    else {
>       eosio::print_f("`_secondary_key`: % not found; not printing.\n", secondary_key.to_string());    }
>
>    eosio::print_f("`printbys` finished executing.\n"); }
>
> [[eosio::action]] void binary_extension_contract::modifyp(eosio::name
> primary_key, name n) {    eosio::print_f("`modifyp` executing.\n");
>        auto index{_table.get_index<"index1"_n>()};    auto iter {index.find(primary_key.value)};
>        if (iter != _table.get_index<"index1"_n>().end()) {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % found; modifying `_primary_key`.\n", primary_key.to_string());
>       index.modify(iter, _self, [&](auto& row) {
>          row._primary_key = n;
>       });    }    else {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % not found; not modifying `_primary_key`.\n", primary_key.to_string());    }
>
>    eosio::print_f("`modifyp` finished executing.\n"); }
>
> [[eosio::action]] void binary_extension_contract::modifys(eosio::name
> primary_key, name n) {    eosio::print_f("`modifys` executing.\n");
>        auto index{_table.get_index<"index1"_n>()};    auto iter {index.find(primary_key.value)};
>        if (iter != _table.get_index<"index1"_n>().end()) {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % found; modifying `_secondary_key`.\n", primary_key.to_string());
>       index.modify(iter, _self, [&](auto& row) {
>          row._secondary_key = n;
>       });    }    else {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % not found; not modifying `_secondary_key`.\n", primary_key.to_string());    }
>
>    eosio::print_f("`modifys` finished executing.\n"); } ```
>
> **binary_extension_contract.abi**
>
> ```javascript {
>     "____comment": "This file was generated with eosio-abigen. DO NOT EDIT ",
>     "version": "eosio::abi/1.1",
>     "types": [],
>     "structs": [
>         {
>             "name": "modifyp",
>             "base": "",
>             "fields": [
>                 {
>                     "name": "primary_key",
>                     "type": "name"
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "name": "n",
>                     "type": "name"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "modifys",
>             "base": "",
>             "fields": [
>                 {
>                     "name": "primary_key",
>                     "type": "name"
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "name": "n",
>                     "type": "name"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "printbyp",
>             "base": "",
>             "fields": [
>                 {
>                     "name": "primary_key",
>                     "type": "name"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "printbys",
>             "base": "",
>             "fields": [
>                 {
>                     "name": "secondary_key",
>                     "type": "name"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "regpkey",
>             "base": "",
>             "fields": [
>                 {
>                     "name": "primary_key",
>                     "type": "name"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "structure",
>             "base": "",
>             "fields": [
>                 {
>                     "name": "_primary_key",
>                     "type": "name"
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "name": "_secondary_key",
>                     "type": "name"
>                 }
>             ]
>         }
>     ],
>     "actions": [
>         {
>             "name": "modifyp",
>             "type": "modifyp",
>             "ricardian_contract": ""
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "modifys",
>             "type": "modifys",
>             "ricardian_contract": ""
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "printbyp",
>             "type": "printbyp",
>             "ricardian_contract": ""
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "printbys",
>             "type": "printbys",
>             "ricardian_contract": ""
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "regpkey",
>             "type": "regpkey",
>             "ricardian_contract": ""
>         }
>     ],
>     "tables": [
>         {
>             "name": "table",
>             "type": "structure",
>             "index_type": "i64",
>             "key_names": [],
>             "key_types": []
>         }
>     ],
>     "ricardian_clauses": [],
>     "variants": [] } ```
>
> <hr>
>
> Take note of the action `regpkey`, and the struct `structure` in
> `con.hpp` and `con.cpp`; the parts of the contract we will be
> upgrading.
>
> **binary_extension_contract.hpp**
>
> ```c++ [[eosio::action]] void regpkey (eosio::name primary_key); ```
>
> ```c++ struct [[eosio::table]] structure {
>     eosio::name _primary_key;
>     eosio::name _secondary_key;
>
>     uint64_t primary_key()   const { return _primary_key.value;   }
>     uint64_t secondary_key() const { return _secondary_key.value; } }; ```
>
> **binary_extension_contract.cpp**
>
> ```c++ [[eosio::action]] void binary_extension_contract::regpkey(name
> primary_key) {    eosio::print_f("`regpkey` executing.\n");
>        auto index{_table.get_index<"index1"_n>()}; ///< `index` represents `_table` organized by `index1`.    auto iter
> {index.find(primary_key.value) }; ///< Note: the type returned by
> `index.find` is different than the type returned by `_table.find`.
>        if (iter == _table.get_index<"index1"_n>().end()) {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % not found; registering.\n", primary_key.to_string());
>       _table.emplace(_self, [&](auto& row) {
>          row._primary_key   = primary_key;
>          row._secondary_key = "nothin"_n;
>       });    }    else {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % found; not registering.\n", primary_key.to_string());    }
>
>    eosio::print_f("`regpkey` finished executing.\n"); } ```
>
> And their corresponding sections in the `.abi` files:
>
> **binary_extension_contract.abi**
>
> ```javascript {
>     "name": "regpkey",
>     "base": "",
>     "fields": [
>         {
>             "name": "primary_key",
>             "type": "name"
>         }
>     ] } ```
>
> ```javascript {
>     "name": "structure",
>     "base": "",
>     "fields": [
>         {
>             "name": "_primary_key",
>             "type": "name"
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "_secondary_key",
>             "type": "name"
>         }
>     ] } ```
>
> <hr>
>
> Now, let's start up a blockchain instance, compile this smart
> contract, and test it out.
>
> ``` ~/binary_extension_contract $ eosio-cpp
> binary_extension_contract.cpp -o binary_extension_contract.wasm ```
>
> ``` ~/binary_extension_contract $ cleos set contract eosio ./ ```
>
> ``` Reading WASM from
> /Users/john.debord/binary_extension_contract/binary_extension_contract.wasm...
> Publishing contract... executed transaction:
> 6c5c7d869a5be67611869b5f300bc452bc57d258d11755f12ced99c7d7fe154c  4160
> bytes  729 us
> #         eosio <= eosio::setcode               "0000000000ea30550000d7600061736d01000000018f011760000060017f0060027f7f0060037f7f7f017f6000017e60067...
> #         eosio <= eosio::setabi                "0000000000ea3055d1020e656f73696f3a3a6162692f312e310006076d6f646966797000020b7072696d6172795f6b65790...
> warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the
> network yet ```
>
> Next, let's push some data to our contract.
>
> ``` ~/binary_extension_contract $ cleos push action eosio regpkey
> '{"primary_key":"eosio.name"}' -p eosio ```
>
> ``` executed transaction:
> 3c708f10dcbf4412801d901eb82687e82287c2249a29a2f4e746d0116d6795f0  104
> bytes  248 us
> #         eosio <= eosio::regpkey               {"primary_key":"eosio.name"} [(eosio,regpkey)->eosio]: CONSOLE OUTPUT
> BEGIN ===================== `regpkey` executing. `_primary_key`:
> eosio.name not found; registering. `regpkey` finished executing.
> [(eosio,regpkey)->eosio]: CONSOLE OUTPUT END   =====================
> warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the
> network yet ```
>
> Finally, let's read back the data we have just written.
>
> ``` ~/binary_extension_contract $ cleos push action eosio printbyp
> '{"primary_key":"eosio.name"}' -p eosio ```
>
> ``` executed transaction:
> e9b77d3cfba322a7a3a93970c0c883cb8b67e2072a26d714d46eef9d79b2f55e  104
> bytes  227 us
> #         eosio <= eosio::printbyp              {"primary_key":"eosio.name"} [(eosio,printbyp)->eosio]: CONSOLE OUTPUT
> BEGIN ===================== `printbyp` executing. `_primary_key`:
> eosio.name found; printing. {eosio.name, nothin} `printbyp` finished
> executing. [(eosio,printbyp)->eosio]: CONSOLE OUTPUT END  
> ===================== warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet ```
>
> <hr>
>
> Now, let's upgrade the smart contract by adding a new field to the
> table and a new parameter to an action while **NOT** wrapping the new
> field/parameter in an `eosio::binary_extension` type and see what
> happens:
>
> **binary_extension_contract.hpp**
>
> ```diff
> +[[eosio::action]] void regpkey (eosio::name primary_key, eosio::name secondary_key);
> -[[eosio::action]] void regpkey (eosio::name primary_key); ```
>
> ```diff struct [[eosio::table]] structure {
>     eosio::name _primary_key;
>     eosio::name _secondary_key;
> +   eosio::name _non_binary_extension_key;
>
>     uint64_t primary_key()   const { return _primary_key.value;   }
>     uint64_t secondary_key() const { return _secondary_key.value; } }; ```
>
> **binary_extension_contract.cpp**
>
> ```diff
> +[[eosio::action]] void binary_extension_contract::regpkey(name primary_key, name secondary_key) {
> -[[eosio::action]] void binary_extension_contract::regpkey(name primary_key) {    eosio::print_f("`regpkey` executing.\n");
>        auto index{_table.get_index<"index1"_n>()}; ///< `index` represents `_table` organized by `index1`.    auto iter
> {index.find(primary_key.value) }; ///< Note: the type returned by
> `index.find` is different than the type returned by `_table.find`.
>        if (iter == _table.get_index<"index1"_n>().end()) {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % not found; registering.\n", primary_key.to_string());
>       _table.emplace(_self, [&](auto& row) {
>          row._primary_key   = primary_key;
> +        if (secondary_key) {
> +           row._secondary_key = secondary_key;
> +         }
> +         else {
>             row._secondary_key = "nothin"_n;
> +         }
>       });    }    else {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % found; not registering.\n", primary_key.to_string());    }
>
>    eosio::print_f("`regpkey` finished executing.\n"); } ```
>
> **binary_extension_contract.abi** ```diff {
>     "name": "regpkey",
>     "base": "",
>     "fields": [
>         {
>             "name": "primary_key",
>             "type": "name"
> +       },
> +       {
> +           "name": "secondary_key",
> +           "type": "name"
>         }
>     ] } ```
>
> ```diff {
>     "name": "structure",
>     "base": "",
>     "fields": [
>         {
>             "name": "_primary_key",
>             "type": "name"
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "_secondary_key",
>             "type": "name"
> +       },
> + {
> +           "name": "_non_binary_extension_key",
> +           "type": "name"
>         }
>     ] } ```
>
> Next, let's upgrade the contract and try to read from our table and
> write to our table the original way:
>
> ``` ~/binary_extension_contract $ eosio-cpp
> binary_extension_contract.cpp -o binary_extension_contract.wasm ```
>
> ``` ~/binary_extension_contract $ cleos set contract eosio ./ ```
>
> ``` Reading WASM from
> /Users/john.debord/binary_extension_contract/binary_extension_contract.wasm...
> Publishing contract... executed transaction:
> b8ea485842fa5645e61d35edd97e78858e062409efcd0a4099d69385d9bc6b3e  4408
> bytes  664 us
> #         eosio <= eosio::setcode               "0000000000ea30550000a2660061736d01000000018f011760000060017f0060027f7f0060037f7f7f017f6000017e60067...
> #         eosio <= eosio::setabi                "0000000000ea305583030e656f73696f3a3a6162692f312e310006076d6f646966797000020b7072696d6172795f6b65790...
> warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the
> network yet ```
>
> ``` ~/binary_extension_contract $ cleos push action eosio printbyp
> '{"primary_key":"eosio.name"}' -p eosio ```
>
> ``` Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure Error
> Details: assertion failure with message: read ```
>
> Whoops! We aren't able to read the data we've previously written to
> our table!
>
> ``` ~/binary_extension_contract $ cleos push action eosio regpkey
> '{"primary_key":"eosio.name2"}' -p eosio ```
>
> ``` Error 3015014: Pack data exception Error Details: Missing field
> 'secondary_key' in input object while processing struct 'regpkey' ```
>
> Whoops! We aren't able to write to our table the original way with the
> upgraded action either!
>
> <hr>
>
> Ok, let's back up and wrap the new field and the new action parameter
> in an `eosio::binary_extension` type:
>
> **binary_extension_contract.hpp**
>
> ```diff
> +[[eosio::action]] void regpkey (eosio::name primary_key. eosio::binary_extension<eosio::name> secondary_key);
> -[[eosio::action]] void regpkey (eosio::name primary_key, eosio::name secondary_key); ```
>
> ```diff struct [[eosio::table]] structure {
>     eosio::name                          _primary_key;
>     eosio::name                          _secondary_key;
> +   eosio::binary_extension<eosio::name> _binary_extension_key;
> -   eosio::name                          _non_binary_extension_key;
>
>     uint64_t primary_key()   const { return _primary_key.value;   }
>     uint64_t secondary_key() const { return _secondary_key.value; } }; ```
>
> **binary_extension_contract.cpp**
>
> ```diff
> +[[eosio::action]] void binary_extension_contract::regpkey(name primary_key, binary_extension<name> secondary_key) {
> -[[eosio::action]] void binary_extension_contract::regpkey(name primary_key, name secondary_key) {    eosio::print_f("`regpkey`
> executing.\n");
>        auto index{_table.get_index<"index1"_n>()}; ///< `index` represents `_table` organized by `index1`.    auto iter
> {index.find(primary_key.value) }; ///< Note: the type returned by
> `index.find` is different than the type returned by `_table.find`.
>        if (iter == _table.get_index<"index1"_n>().end()) {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % not found; registering.\n", primary_key.to_string());
>       _table.emplace(_self, [&](auto& row) {
>          row._primary_key   = primary_key;
>          if (secondary_key) {
> +           row._secondary_key = secondary_key.value();
> -           row._secondary_key = secondary_key;
>           }
>           else {
>             row._secondary_key = "nothin"_n;
>           }
>       });    }    else {
>       eosio::print_f("`_primary_key`: % found; not registering.\n", primary_key.to_string());    }
>
>    eosio::print_f("`regpkey` finished executing.\n"); } ```
>
> **binary_extension_contract.abi** ```diff {
>     "name": "regpkey",
>     "base": "",
>     "fields": [
>         {
>             "name": "primary_key",
>             "type": "name"
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "secondary_key",
> +           "type": "name$"
> -           "type": "name"
>         }
>     ] } ```
>
> ```diff {
>     "name": "structure",
>     "base": "",
>     "fields": [
>         {
>             "name": "_primary_key",
>             "type": "name"
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "_secondary_key",
>             "type": "name"
>         },    {
> +           "name": "_binary_extension_key",
> +           "type": "name$"
> -           "name": "_non_binary_extension_key",
> -           "type": "name"
>         }
>     ] } ```
>
> Note the `$` after the types now; this indicates that this type is an
> `eosio::binary_extension` type field. ```diff {
>     "name": "secondary_key",
> +   "type": "name$"
> -   "type": "name" } ```
>
> ```diff {
>     "name": "_binary_extension_key",
> +   "type": "name$"
> -   "type": "name" } ```
>
> Now, let's upgrade the contract again and try to read/write from/to
> our table:
>
> ``` ~/binary_extension_contract $ cleos set contract eosio ./ ```
>
> ``` Reading WASM from
> /Users/john.debord/binary_extension_contract/binary_extension_contract.wasm...
> Publishing contract... executed transaction:
> 497584d4e43ec114dbef83c134570492893f49eacb555d0cd47d08ea4a3a72f7  4696
> bytes  648 us
> #         eosio <= eosio::setcode               "0000000000ea30550000cb6a0061736d01000000018f011760000060017f0060027f7f0060037f7f7f017f6000017e60017...
> #         eosio <= eosio::setabi                "0000000000ea305581030e656f73696f3a3a6162692f312e310006076d6f646966797000020b7072696d6172795f6b65790...
> warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the
> network yet ```
>
> ``` ~/binary_extension_contract $ cleos push action eosio printbyp
> '{"primary_key":"eosio.name"}' -p eosio ```
>
> ``` executed transaction:
> 6108f3206e1824fe3a1fdcbc2fe733f38dc07ae3d411a1ccf777ecef56ddec97  104
> bytes  224 us
> #         eosio <= eosio::printbyp              {"primary_key":"eosio.name"} [(eosio,printbyp)->eosio]: CONSOLE OUTPUT
> BEGIN ===================== `printbyp` executing. `_primary_key`:
> eosio.name found; printing. {eosio.name, nothin} `printbyp` finished
> executing. [(eosio,printbyp)->eosio]: CONSOLE OUTPUT END  
> ===================== warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet ```
>
> ``` ~/binary_extension_contract $ cleos push action eosio regpkey
> '{"primary_key":"eosio.name2"}' -p eosio ```
>
> ``` executed transaction:
> 75a135d1279a9c967078b0ebe337dc0cd58e1ccd07e370a899d9769391509afc  104
> bytes  227 us
> #         eosio <= eosio::regpkey               {"primary_key":"eosio.name2"} [(eosio,regpkey)->eosio]: CONSOLE OUTPUT
> BEGIN ===================== `regpkey` executing. `_primary_key`:
> eosio.name2 not found; registering. `regpkey` finished executing.
> [(eosio,regpkey)->eosio]: CONSOLE OUTPUT END   =====================
> warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the
> network yet ```
>
> Nice! The smart contract is now backwards compatible for the future
> use of its tables and/or actions.
>
> <hr>
>
> Just keep these simple rules in mind when upgrading a smart contract.
> If you are adding a new field to a struct currently in use by a
> `eosio::multi_index` be **SURE** to:
> - add the field at the end of the struct.
> - wrap the type using an `eosio::binary_extension` type.
> ````

All credit goes to [John DeBord](https://github.com/johndebord)